# Python: Best way to set a reference for a class attribute that has not been defined yet and what default to use?

Tags: python, class, oop, composition

This is a little example of a larger project I have. I would like to define some sort of bracket blueprint with composition and have some attributes of these classes as a reference to other class properties that can change. I am not sure how to set the defaults, since None is immutable. The example is pretty clear.

```py
class Player:
  def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name


class Match:
  def __init__(self, player1, player2):
      self.player1 = player1
      self.player2 = player2
      self._winner = None

  @property
  def winner(self):
      return self._winner

  @winner.setter
  def winner(self, value):
      self._winner = value

class Bracket:
  def __init__(self, player1=player1, player2=player2, player2=player3):
      self.m1 = Match(player1, player2)
      self.m2 = Match(player1, self.m1.winner) ### I want ot have a reference.

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Player('John')
  p2 = Player('Dave')
  p3 = Player('Mike')
  b = Bracket(p1, p2, p3)

  b.m1.winner = p1

### I would like to dynamically have b.m2 with John as player 2, but since the default is None, it is immutable. Any recommendations?
```

Comment: why would it be immutable if the default is `None`?

Comment: I would like to create another instance of match (self.m2) where it references the winner of self.m1, but that hasn't happened. (I could create self.m2 after the winner of self.m1 has been determined) but it si not how I'd like it.

Comment: Why are you making it complicated?

Comment: I think you could accomplish this with a difference constructor that accepted a `Match` as argument and save that internally. And then the logic would be implemented in the `m2` property getter. I'm with Peter, though, this seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Alternatively, create a `WinnerOf` class that stores a `Match` attribute. The `name` attribute getter could then return `None` or the player name. In `Match`, `m1` and `m2` could be `Player` or `WinnerOf` objects. Both ideas boil down to storing a reference to the `Match` object whose outcome is not known yet, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: Why is `winner` a `property`?